# Getting HibernateOptimisticLocking Exception while saving an object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have a model file whose code is:

**Signature.java**

```
public class Signature implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private int version;
    private byte[] signatureImage;
    private String signatureImageName;
    private String name;
    private String title; 
    // the getters setters methods 
}
```

Here in this object I am getting the `signatureImage` from jsp using `MultipartFile` and then saving the bytes in to this field. I am saving this object from my controller and daohibernate code is as follows:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(signature);
```

Now I am getting an error :

> :While Handling request:->HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException, e:: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class com.model.Signature with identifier []: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.model.Signature#]

Now this is single call to the `saveOrUpdate` query no threads then also I am getting this error.

Comment: This is exactly what it says: some other service modified this record in the database. Therefore version information does not fit, and your update is rejected. You will have to analyze what modified this record.

Comment: SIr, my update is working fine . When I update a record then no error comes when I save a new record then it shows this error.  Actually , I have performed delete operation also on this table . So can that delete operation cause this error?

Comment: Do you perhaps use a primary key in your new record which already exists?

Comment: No Sir . I am not reusing the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the error here . The id that was coming was not null it was "" (empty) .

So that is why it was trying to update the record not save.

So by changing the value of id to null it saved the record.

Thanks